# How to create an xml database?

Tags: xml, database

How can I create an XML database?

Please tell me any DBMS help me to create database stored XML document.

I will use an existing server for querying but first create the XML database itself.

---

I realy confused between xml db and db that support xml

plz explain the difference between them and how to create both?

Answer (score 4):

Any database can store text, so the immediate option would be to store the xml as text.

But some databases have added an XML data type in order to allow for storing the XML, checking that the schema validates (proper structure, not a fragment), and retrieving values from the XML stored in the database with XPATH/XQUERY syntax.

Support differs between Oracle 10g+, SQL Server 2000+, Postgres, MySQL 5.1+ so we'd need more information before recommending a specific one.

> I am really confused between xml db and db that support xml

Based on [this information from Wikipeidia about XML Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database), it comes down to what each database product supports.  SQL Server and Oracle support native XML at their respective versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused between an "XML database" and a database that supports XML. SQL Server for example, is a relational database that supports XML. In fact, it has an XML data type that allows you to store XML documents and perform XML operations against that data type.

Answer (score 1):

I have always found Ron Bourret's article a valuable overview:
http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XMLAndDatabases.htm

The simple answer is that XML can be used for many purposes and that different ones need different database requirements. I have used several "XML databases" and found that different ones work better or worse for different requirements.

I have at least the following requirements:

- A database of large XML documents where I am not interested in searching inside the documents
- An XML representation of a relational database
- A large number of smallish XML documents that I wish to index in detail (i.e. searching by XPath within each
- RDFXML

I would use different approaches for each of these. You should also be concerned with whether the databses is small and can fit into memory or whether you will need to have a larger system.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app for that! http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/xml/index.html

"Berkeley DB XML is an open source, embeddable XML database with XQuery-based access to documents stored in containers and indexed based on their content."

Really a great tool.